# Traceback (most recent call last): minSize=(30, 30) TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'CascadeClassifier' or its derivative)

Tags: python-2.7, face-detection, haar-classifier

Now here is the code:

```
import cv2
import sys


cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
cascPath2= "haarcascade_eye.xml"

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
eyeCascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath2)


image = cv2.imread('face-04.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
     gray,
     scaleFactor=1.1,
     minNeighbors=5,
     minSize=(30, 30)
     )
print("Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces)))

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

Face_gray=gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
Face_color=image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

eyes=eyeCascade.detectMultiScale(Face_gray)

for(ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
    cv2.rectangle(Face_color, (ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Faces found", image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

1. I have taken care of the path for the images as well as the XML file
2. I have reinstalled the software
3. I cannot understand why I am getting this type error. I have tried running the same code on another pc and it worked properly.

Comment: Can you please post error log?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem!

When you want to download the XML files for object detection, download them using the "Raw" button located at the top right corner. Then use "Save as" and store the file in your project directory.

First I got this error because I just "save as " the link.

[image: Image showing the buttons]

Comment: Even if i write my own code, the same problem occurs